# Как принудительно отобразить иконку программы в трее?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть программа WF, главная форма - это Drop Zone. Пользователь перетаскивает на ее файлы. Процесс обработки данных занимает от 1 до 5 секунд. Сейчас я информирую пользователя о том, что программа обрабатывает данные - анимированная иконка в трее. Но дело в том, что может быть настроено вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
и пользователь ничего не видит, что идет обработка данных, т.к. иконка спрятана. Вопрос у меня такой - можно ли из программы отобразить иконку программы на панели принудительно? Или, может, есть какие другие идеи?

Comment: Добавьте прогресс иконке на таксбаре: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFYNP.png

Comment: Идея супер. Может скинешь ссылку с каким-нибудь примером? Спасибо

Comment: В WPF есть [TaskbarItemInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo) со свойствами `ProgressState` и `ProgressValue`, в WinForms тоже это должно быть в наличии, с WinAPI как минимум это можно добавить

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1146574/6766879

Comment: спасибо, а по первому вопросу - я так понял, что нельзя изменить настройки?

Comment: Я думаю (уверен), что нет. Это сделано для "защиты" пользователя — чтобы он мог скрыть неугодные иконки и не видеть их, вряд ли в системе предусмотрен метод обхода этого

Comment: [ПРОГРАММИРУЕМ WINDOWS 7: TASKBAR. ЧАСТЬ 1 - PROGRESS BAR](https://blog.zwezdin.com/2009/windows7-taskbar-part1/)